# Как узнать адрес блока в вызове call

Tags: ассемблер

Добрый день.
Ситуация: дизассемблирую приложение и вижу в получившимся коде такой кусок:

```
e8ae5f0100    call    0x000adace    _myFunc
```

Т.е. дизассемблер из шестнадцатеричного кода (`e8ae5f0100`) получил адрес вызываемого блока (`0x000adace`) и по нему в бинарнике нашел строку с названием этого блока (`"_myFunc"`).

Вопрос: как вручную получить адрес этого вызываемого участка, зная лишь последовательность кодов, например, `e8ae5f0100`.
Известно при этом, что вызывается именно функция, а не какой-то локальный блок.

Comment: >и по нему в бинарнике нашел строку с названием этого блока ("_myFunc").

Врядли по этому адресу расположена такая строка. Возможно в бинарнике присутствует отладочная информация, где указаны имена соответствующих процедур, так что _myFunс в данном случае это скорее всего просто комментарий, добавленный дизассемблером.

Comment: @insolor, да я это и имел в виду, он читает эту информацию из стандартного сегмента Mach-O binary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Э, не всё так просто. Сначала, выкачиваем или заказываем халявный диск с [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). Открываем том 2 *Instruction Set Reference* и видим там:

[image]

Обращаем внимание, что вызов **relative** - относительный. Далее, **displacement
relative to next instruction** - смещение относительно следующей инструкции.

Соответственно, берём операнд нашего `E8`, как знаковый `DWORD` и складываем с виртуальным адресом след. опкода.

Вуаля, в результате получаем абсолютный виртуальный адрес вызываемой подпрограммы.

(Арифметику не могу продемонстрировать, т.к. вы не указали VA вашей инструкции)

Comment: Если я правильно все понял, то адрес - 0xf486.

Comment: Кстати по имеющимся данным виртуальный адрес можно вычислить:)

Comment: @insolor, стоп, это я дурак, не туда гляжу, все верно  - 0x00097B20. Спасибо большое, @AlLeween.